# Storing values from JavaScript forms

Tags: javascript

In a bit of a pickle here. So I have these 3 forms that using the JavaScript code matches a string to an int value. Right now, the user is able to continuously click the "Enter!" button for the 3 forms and have an alert pop up with the corresponding int value of whatever string is chosen.

What I would like to do is to keep track of the int values of what the user produces and then output the sum. For example, if the user chooses "Electronics" three times in the first form, -300 would be outputted since the dictionary matches "Electronics" with -100.

Any ideas how? I've tried several things with no luck.

Thanks so much Stack Overflow community <3

Below is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Eco-Calculator</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "calculator.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/javascript" href = "calculator.js">
<script src = "calculator.js"></script>
<script></script>
</head>

<div id="calculator">
<!-- Screen and clear key -->
<div class="top">
    <span class="clear">C</span>
    <div class="screen"></div>
</div>

<div class="keys">
    <!-- operators and other keys -->
<form>
Select consumption:
  <select id="mySelect1">
    <option>Clothing</option>
    <option>Electronics</option>
    <option>Furnishing</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <span><input type="button" onclick="getOption1()" value="Enter!"></span>
</form>

<p id="demo1"></p>

<form>
  Enter food/item:
  <select id="mySelect2">
    <option>Quick Snack</option>
    <option>Home-Made</option>
    <option>Take-Out</option>
    <option>Dine-In</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <span><input type="button" onclick="getOption2()" value="Enter!"></span>
</form>

<p id="demo2"></p>

<form>
  Enter transportation:
  <select id="mySelect3">
    <option>Walking</option>
    <option>Biking</option>
    <option>Public</option>
    <option>Driving</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <span><input type="button" onclick="getOption3()" value="Enter!"></span>
</form> 
<p id="demo3"></p>

</div>
```

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
function getOption1() {
var obj = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
//document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = 
var tmp = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text
var map = {"Clothing": -50, "Electronics": -100, "Furnishing": -75}
alert(map[tmp])
}

function getOption2() {
var obj = document.getElementById("mySelect2");
//document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 
var tmp = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
var map = {"Quick Snack": 5, "Home-Made": 50, "Take-Out": -25, "Dine-In":        -50}
alert(map[tmp])
}

function getOption3() {
var obj = document.getElementById("mySelect3");
//document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = 
var tmp = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
var map = {"Walking": 25, "Biking": 50, "Public": 30, "Driving": -50}
alert(map[tmp])
}
```

Comment: This question is rather broad; there are many options for storing the state: posting to a server that stores in a database, maintaining state in a cookie, using local storage, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the equivalent values in the options with data attributes:

```
<select id="mySelect1">
    <option data-cost="-50">Clothing</option>
    <option data-cost="-100">Electronics</option>
    <option data-cost="-75">Furnishing</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="getOption1()" value="Enter!">
```

Then in the JavaScript, keep running totals in global variables:

```
// This is defined in the global space so it doesn't vanish when the function exits
var total1 = 0;

function getOption1() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
    // note the use of an extra plus here to convert the string to a number
    total1 += +obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-cost");
    alert(total1);
}
```

That way you're not using fiddly matching of text, and you're keeping the associated data in the options.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all changes to the form are made before it's submitted:

Have you tried creating a global variable `sum` which you add the value of `map[tmp]` to every time one of the `getOption`s is run?
Then you could `alert(map[tmp] + " (total:" + sum + ")")` or something of that sort.

Assuming that the form is submitted between each change to the form:

Use `localStorage` or, for maximum compatibility, cookies to keep track of the variable in between sessions in much the same way

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is my first day writing JavaScript. 

What do you mean all changes are made before submission?

I tried that but got the syntax wrong, ill try what you wrote.

Don't really understand local storage or cookies, could you explain? 

How do I know whether the form is submitted between each change to the form? 

Thanks so much!!!!